# How do I fetch automatically new kubernetes clusters created manually on google cloud

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

Supposed that I create a new k8s cluster in console.cloud.google.com interface. Running `kubectl config get-contexts` currently shows only the current cluster, not the new ones.

How do I fetch it locally so I can run the usual commands from my terminal on the new cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `gcloud` command line tool.

First you need to install and setup it, you can follow the guide that suits your environment from the official page: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads

After you need to run the following command:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials <clustername>
```

More details here: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/get-credentials